# Hyperparameters to make a CART / RF out of LightGBM

Tags: python, cart, random-forest, lightgbm, gbm

I want to use the LightGBM framework as a CART and a Random Forest. This should be easily achievable by choosing the right hyper parameters for the algorithm.

I think that I should do the following:

Random Forest:

```
random_forest = lgb.LGBMRegressor(boosting_type="rf", bagging_freq=1, bagging_fraction=0.8, feature_fraction=0.8)
```

CART:

```
cart = lgb.LGBMRegressor(boosting_type="rf", num_iterations=1, num_leafs=131072)
```

What do you think? Did I miss something? Is my approach correct?